# R: How to increment the incrementing variable within a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, increment

I'm trying to manually increment the *i* variable when a condition is met.

```
for(i in 1:x){
   if(condition){
      i <- i + 2
      }
   }
```

When debugging, the (i<-i+2) line is definitely being run, but i still only increments by 1, instead of 3. (+2 from the line and an additional +1 from the auto increment)

How can I increment while I'm within the loop?

Comment: Why don't you use `while(i <= x)` instead of `for(i in 1:x)`?

Comment: It's extremely bad practice to do this even in languages that support it. `repeat` or `while` is a better idiom if you plan on modifying the looping in multiple places variable. Your future self will also thank you immensely if they ever go back to this code. Colin's code is a good alternative for cases where you are definitely going to iterate over the entire sequence but need to change a different variable. Deviating from the contract in the `for` idiom is just not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

So essentially you want to skip a few loop iterations based on a condition. It's a design choice that's rightfully frowned upon, but if you must, you need `next`. The following code skips the third, fifth and seventh iteration:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  if(i %in% c(3,5,7)){
    next
  }
  print(i)
}
```

Say you need to increment with 3 based on a certain condition, then you can use a temporary variable that helps you skip a number of steps. Note that this does go through every iteration, it just breaks out of the iteration in time:

```
skip <- 0 # the temporary variable helping us keeping track of the iterations
for(i in 1:10){
  if(i == 5){  # the condition that causes the skip
    skip <- 3
  }
  if(skip > 0){ # the control that skips as long as necessary
    skip <- skip - 1
    next
  }
  print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the loop, the value of the variable `i` is stored in `tmp*`. This means that whenever we reach the top the loop, `i` resets. For example

```
for(i in 1:2){
  message(i)
  i <- 10
  message(i)
}
#1
#10
#2
#10
```

To get what you want, you could have something like:

```
k =1 
for(i in 1:10){
   if(condition) k <- k + 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the sequence is created, you pretty much lose a lot of control over looping.  In cases like this, I change it into a while loop and then do the conditional incrementing/decrementing at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with joris-meys, it's "frowned upon". But... A more simple approach is:

```
for(i in (0:3)*2+1){
  cat(i," ")
}
```

or

```
for(i in (1:4)){
  cat(i," ")
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
for(i in seq(0, 10, 2) ){
  print(i)
}
```

you can do this..

Comment: not even close to doing what OP wants. He needs a condition