# Why are For Loops Not Effective in R and Looping Through Indices

Tags: r

I am doing R practice exercises from the R-bloggers site. This is the problem I was working on:

> Create a function that will return TRUE if a given integer is inside a vector.

The solution code provided is:

```
f.exists <- function (v, x) {
  exist <- FALSE
  i <- 1

  while (i <= length (v) & !exist) {

    if (v[i] == x) {
      exist <- TRUE
    }
  i <- 1 + i
  }
  exist
}
```

However, my attempt was:

```
isInside <- function(x, y) {
  i <- 1
  for (i in x) {
    print(i)
    if (x[i] == y) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
    else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
} 

test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10.25,100)
isInside(test,10.25)
```

This returns `[1] 1 [1] False` meaning it only looped through once and exited once it hit false. It should have returned true though, since 10.25 is in the vector `x`. I am not sure why the `if` statement does not work since it should loop through each index of `x` to see if the number is in the vector.

Additionally, I found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556911/r-how-to-increment-the-incrementing-variable-within-a-for-loop), that says you should use `while` loops rather than `for` loops. Why are `for` loops such bad practice? And is there something inherently wrong with my `for` loop that makes it not work?

Comment: `for` and `while` will carry the same efficiency (or lack of it).  You only iterate once because you say `if (x[i] == y) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE)`. You *always* `return`. If you instead want to keep going, then don't `return(FALSE)` in the else` clause of the `for` loop. (There is no way in your logic to continue past the first pass in the loop.)

Comment: (Do you realize that `return` breaks out of any `for`, `while`, `repeat`, or anything else? It escapes the function immediately.)

Comment: Yes, I realize saying ```return``` breaks the loop. However, when I remove the ```return```'s and say:  ```isInside <- function(x, y) {
  i <- 1
  for (i in x) {
    print(i)
    if (x[i] == y) {
      print(x[i])
      #return(TRUE)
      exist <- TRUE
    }
    else {
      #return(FALSE)
      exist <- FALSE
    }
  }
  exist
}``` it says I'm missing a value where TRUE/FALSE is needed, which is why I assumed I needed the ```return``` TRUE/FALSE

Comment: (Sorry for pasting that new attempt as a comment, didn't think it was appropriate to put it in my original post.) @r2evans

Comment: If you want to return true when you find a match, then perhaps just `if (x[i] == y) return(TRUE)` and do nothing when `x[i] != y`. That way, the loop will go to the next iteration and try again. When the loop is done, you should probably `return(FALSE)`, since the only way the code execution would get to that point in the function is if the entire vector is compared and nothing caused immediate return.

Comment: Further, `i` is an element of `x`, not an index on it, so `x[i]` is not appropriate. (And there is no need to pre-instantiate `i <- 1`, since the `for` loop takes care of this for you.)

Comment: Perhaps `function(x, y) { for (el in x) if (el == y) return(TRUE) ; return(FALSE); }`. (This discussion is completely academic, though, since hopefully one would prefer to use `any(x %in% y)`.)

Comment: Yes, the discussion was meant to be academic as I am just trying to practice writing functions on my own from scratch in R. Using the ```any()``` makes it easier and I was not aware of that, but I would not doing it through my own function that way.

Comment: Also, to my understanding ```x[1]``` would mean grabbing the first value of the vector ```x``` and I had thought that in programming, you start at index 0, which is why I pre-instatntiated ```i <- 1```. Would you mind explaining why ```x[i]``` is not finding the element at the ith index of ```x```, unless I am just confused on the wording? Also what is the purpose of the ```;```? I was under the impression that semicolons are not used in R and rather in Java.

Comment: R uses 1-based indexing, not 0-based as in some other languages. It just so happens with your example that on the first pass through the loop, `x[i]` works. This works only because the first several elements of `x` are 1 through 10, coinciding with the indices. But *it is guaranteed to fail* if it gets to the last two elements of `x`. You would assign the value `10.25` and next `100` to `i`. What should `x[i]` be for those two? You are confused about what is going into `i`, not what `x[i]` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dodging the preferred use of R's `%in%` inline operator, let's analyze your function.

1. `for (i in x)` is stepping through each *value* of `x`. This means that on the 11th pass through a loop like this (lacking interruption), `i` would be `10.25` and not `11`. This will fail *logically* when you reference `x[i]`: it won't throw an error (which I believe is a failure of R, to be honest), but it makes no sense (what is `x[10.25]`? what should the next pass of `x[100]` return?). This should either be `for (i in seq_along(x))` or stick with `for (i in x)` and later replace `x[i] == y` with `i == y`.
2. You choose to `return(TRUE)` when a match is found. The `return` function immediately breaks out of the `for` loop and out of the function, returning the value `TRUE`. If the match is not found, you `return(FALSE)`, which also immediately breaks out of the `for` loop and the function, returning the value `FALSE`. I think what you intend is for the loop to continue, so the `else` clause of the `if` statement is ... unnecessary. If you remove the `else` statement, perhaps it'll work better.
3. Minor, you pre-defined `i <- 1`. This hurts or changes nothing, but it is completely unnecessary in R. `i` is not referenced outside of the loop, and as soon as `for` starts, `i` is assigned the first value of `x`. Therefore, you can safely remove `i <- 1` and execution should be unaffected. (This is not code style, it's just unnecessary code.)

Demonstration of one method:

```r
myany <- function(x, y) {
  for (el in x) {
    if (el == y) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10.25,100)
myany(test, 10.25)
# [1] TRUE
```

Alternatively,

```r
myany <- function(x, y) {
  for (ind in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[ind] == y) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```

We can see some of the mistakes in this example:

```r
myany <- function(x, y) {
  for (i in x) {
    message("Comparing ", sQuote(i), " (which is ", sQuote(x[i]), ") with ", sQuote(y))
    if (x[i] == y) {
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

myany(test, 10.25)
# Comparing '1' (which is '1') with '10.25'
# Comparing '2' (which is '2') with '10.25'
# Comparing '3' (which is '3') with '10.25'
# Comparing '4' (which is '4') with '10.25'
# Comparing '5' (which is '5') with '10.25'
# Comparing '6' (which is '6') with '10.25'
# Comparing '7' (which is '7') with '10.25'
# Comparing '8' (which is '8') with '10.25'
# Comparing '9' (which is '9') with '10.25'
# Comparing '10' (which is '10') with '10.25'
# Comparing '10.25' (which is '10') with '10.25'
# Comparing '100' (which is 'NA') with '10.25'
# Error in if (x[i] == y) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here's where we see what is happening. When `i` is `10`, it looks fine, as the 10th element of `test` is indeed 10. However, in the next pass, `i` is `10.25` instead of your expected `11`. R is silently truncating `x[10.25]` into `x[10]`, which is why it says `which is '10'`, since the 10th element is indeed 10. The next pass is where `i` is `100`, and `test[100]` clearly does not exist. In R, when you try to retrieve an index that is outside of the defined length of a vector, it will return `NA` (other languages give an error or core dump when you attempt this).

Comment: My thinking was that ```i``` would increase by 1 each time so ```x[11]``` would ```= 10.25```. So in this case, if ```y = 10.25``` then ```x[11] = 10.25 = y```. And same with ```x[12]``` being ```= 100```. So ```i``` could only go through the length of ```x``` which I should have used ```seq_along(x)``` as you mentioned, or ```length(x)```

Comment: I know that's what you were thinking, that's why I suggested the use of `for (i in seq_along(x))`. But `i` will never be 11 in your code, since you are assigned each ***value*** of `x` to `i`, not each *index* of `x`.

Comment: As Paul demonstrated in that answer, `for (i in x) print(i)` will never show you `11`, it will go from 9 to 10 to 10.25 to 100.

Comment: Thank you, this has all been very helpful in my understanding of R. One last minor question regarding your ```;```'s in your commented code. Are the ```;```'s just representing a break in the code just so I am able to read it since you can't format in comments? Or does it have another purpose in this case

Comment: The use of `;` is solely to present somewhat usable code in a comment. In R, `;` is not required unless you put two or more expressions on a single line (where often a newline is used in source files). On StackOverflow, we cannot well-represent a newline, so I use the `;` so that the code can actually be used. If you type it into a source file and replace `;` with a newline, it might look more appropriate. (If you're doing that, also add newlines after `{`.)

Comment: Yeah that is what I did anyway, but I just wanted to make sure that is how it was intended. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here. As pointed out by r2evans, your loop is exited at the first iteration because of your code. It must return TRUE or FALSE at the first iteration.
Besides, your loop will not work due to a simple mistake: `for (i in x)` cannot work as `x` should evaluate to a vector of integers. You are looking for: `for (i in 1:length(x))`.

```
> for (i in test) {print(i)}
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
[1] 10.25
[1] 100
```

At the 11th iteration R interprets 10.25 as 10 so you are lucky. At the 12th loop, the code would look for the 100st element in `test` and `NA` is returned.

There is a much simpler solution without a loop by using the inherent vectorisation of some R functions:

```
    test <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10.25,100)
    x <- 10.25
    any(test == x)
```

will return:

```
> any(test == x)
[1] TRUE
```

And if you would like to know which element:

```
> which(test == x)
[1] 11
```

As a function:

```
isInside <- function(x, v) return(any(x == v))
isInside(test, 10.25)
```

returns:

```
> isInside(test, 10.25)
[1] TRUE
> isInside(test, 11)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I suggest `seq_along(x)` instead of `1:length(x)`. As an example why, consider if `x <- c()`: one might expect `1:length(x)` to do *nothing* (return a vector also of length 0), but it resolves to `1:0` which returns a vector of length 2 (instead of a vector the same length as `x`). Alternatively, `seq_len` and `seq_along` both deal correctly with zero-length vectors.